# Automation error second time I open a userform and press calendar button

Tags: excel, vba

I have built a vba code that, when a sheet button is pressed, opens a userform and populates some controls into it during run-time. These controls are a bunch of labels, textboxes and buttons. For that textbox where a date value is expected, a calendar button is created next to it also during run-time.

The first time the user opens the userform, the calendar button can be pressed repeteadly without error and the textbox keeps being completed with the selected date. However, if the user exits the userform with the "X" (close) button, opens the userform again, presses the calendar button and clicks on a day label, an error is triggered with following wording:

> Run-time error '-2147418113 (8000ffff)': Automation error

Find below the simplified code I use for the class that handles the day label click event.

I have searched a solution on the web with no success. I also cleared all the code, compiled, and put the code back, but nothing changed.

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents InputLabel As MSForms.Label
Public originTB As Controls

Private Sub InputLabel_click()

    Dim cal_ParentForm_text As String
    Dim cal_ParentCtrl_text As String
    Dim cal_ParentTB As String
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim myWords As String
    Dim word As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim tag_len As Integer


    lFirstDay = Val(InputLabel.Caption)

    'Form_calendar.tag STRUCTURE: FORM,FRAME,TEXTBOXNAME
    count = 0
    word = ""
    myWords = Form_calendar.Tag
    tag_len = Len(myWords)
    For i = 1 To tag_len
        If Mid(myWords, i, 1) = "," Or i = tag_len Then 'End of word
            count = count + 1
            Select Case count
                Case 1 'Form
                    cal_ParentForm_text = word
                    word = ""
                Case 2 'Frame
                    cal_ParentCtrl_text = word
                    word = ""
                Case 3 'TextBoxName
                    cal_ParentTB = word & Mid(myWords, i, 1)
            End Select
        Else
            word = word & Mid(myWords, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i


    'Look for the origin textbox within calendar textbox collection (coll_CalTextBox)
    For Each ctl In coll_CalTextBox
        If ctl.Name = cal_ParentTB Then

            'FOLLOWING LINE TRIGGERS THE ERROR
            ctl.Text = Format(ReturnDate(lFirstDay, lSelMonth, lSelYear), "Short Date")

        End If
    Next ctl

    Unload Form_calendar

End Sub


Function ReturnDate(ByVal lDay As Long, ByVal lMonth As Long, ByVal lYear As Long) As Date
'Returns the date with day, month and year in
'the sequence defined by the system's settings.

    Dim lDayPos As Long              'Day position in date
    Dim lMonthPos As Long            'Month position in date

    lDayPos = Day("01-02-03")
    lMonthPos = Month("01-02-03")

    If lDayPos = 1 And lMonthPos = 2 Then
       ReturnDate = lDay & "/" & lMonth & "/" & lYear
    'AFTER THIS STATEMENT THE ERROR IS TRIGGERED
       Exit Function

    ElseIf lDayPos = 2 And lMonthPos = 1 Then
       ReturnDate = lMonth & "/" & lDay & "/" & lYear
       Exit Function
    ElseIf lDayPos = 3 And lMonthPos = 2 Then
       ReturnDate = lYear & "/" & lMonth & "/" & lDay
       Exit Function
    ElseIf lDayPos = 2 And lMonthPos = 3 Then
       ReturnDate = lYear & "/" & lDay & "/" & lMonth
       Exit Function
    ElseIf lDayPos = 1 And lMonthPos = 3 Then
       ReturnDate = lDay & "/" & lYear & "/" & lMonth
       Exit Function
    ElseIf lMonthPos = 1 And lDayPos = 3 Then
       ReturnDate = lMonth & "/" & lYear & "/" & lDay
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. As you said "presses the calendar button and clicks on a day label," the code of the associated events and the code that "opens a userform and populates some controls into it during run-time." may be more helpful to understand the scenario better.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think I figured out the problem, but I would appreciate your confirmation. Each time the form was opened, same named runtime controls were being created and included within coll_CalTextBox public collection. Therefore when looping the collection and meeting ctl.Name = cal_ParentTB condition I realized that ctl was an "empty" control (created in previous form opening) causing the error. Now I clear the collection before each opening and no more errors. Makes sense to you? I thought that collections were automatically reduced as controls disappeared when closing form.

Comment: Thanks for reply even after solving the problem yourself. That's the spirit flourish SO. and I also think you are absolutely right in clearing old instances.